# cleos get actions returns empty list!

Tags: action

I am running EOS on my computer as a local network.  I created a smart contract and am able to invoke the actions using both cleos commands and through eosjs.  When I run cleos get table command I see the multi-index tables populated as they should be...which means my smart contract is working fine.

However, when I run

```
cleos get actions 'account_name'
```

to see all the actions performed by a specific account, I get an empty list as below:

`#  seq  when                              contract::action => receiver      trx id...   args
===================================================================================`

My nodeos is configured with filter-on option.  Complete configuration below:

> keosd --http-server-address=0.0.0.0:5555 & exec nodeos -e -p eosio --plugin eosio::producer_plugin --plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin --plugin eosio::history_plugin --plugin eosio::history_api_plugin --plugin eosio::http_plugin -d /mnt/dev/data --config-dir /mnt/dev/config --http-server-address=0.0.0.0:7777 --access-control-allow-origin=* --contracts-console --http-validate-host=false —filter-on='*'

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this issues on github it may resolve your query

https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/3583

https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/3915

Comment: Thank you.  I had looked through these issues and as was mentioned in the comments my nodeos was run with history plugin and filter-on options.  Not sure what else I am missing here!

Comment: try to hard reply blockchain by nodeos --hard-replay-blockchain this and after that try to get actions

Comment: Anytime...Happy coding :-)